# Why am I getting InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

So far I have this:

```
public double checkValueWithin(int min, int max) {
    double num;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = reader.nextDouble();                         
    while (num < min || num > max) {                 
        System.out.print("Invalid. Re-enter number: "); 
        num = reader.nextDouble();                         
    }
    return num;
}
```

and this:

```
public void askForMarks() {
    double marks[] = new double[student];
    int index = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (index < student) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a mark (0..30): ");
        marks[index] = (double) checkValueWithin(0, 30); 
        index++;
    }
}
```

When I test this, it can't take double number and I got this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at MarkingSystem.checkValueWithin(MarkingSystem.java:25)
at MarkingSystem.askForMarks(MarkingSystem.java:44)
at World.main(World.java:6)
Java Result: 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html Look at this. Maybe the scanner was not able to parse what you entered into the console? For example, it asked for a number, you entered "hello"?

Comment: Try doing "nextFloat" instead.

Comment: Remove Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); from the askForMarks();  Everything works for me then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you can see the nature of [Scanner](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html):

> double nextDouble()
>
> Returns the next token as a double. **If the next token is not a float or
>   is out of range, InputMismatchException is thrown.**

Try to catch the exception

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage()); //try to find out specific reason.
}
```

**UPDATE**

**CASE 1**

I tried your code and there is nothing wrong with it. Your are getting that error because **you must have entered `String` value**. When I entered a numeric value, it runs without any errors. But once I entered `String` it `throw` the same `Exception` which you have mentioned in your question.

**CASE 2**

You have entered something, which is **out of range** as I have mentioned above.

I'm really wondering what you could have tried to enter. In my system, it is running perfectly without changing a single line of code. Just copy as it is and try to compile and run it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Test().askForMarks(5);
    }

    public void askForMarks(int student) {
        double marks[] = new double[student];
        int index = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (index < student) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a mark (0..30): ");
            marks[index] = (double) checkValueWithin(0, 30); 
            index++;
        }
    }

    public double checkValueWithin(int min, int max) {
        double num;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = reader.nextDouble();                         
        while (num < min || num > max) {                 
            System.out.print("Invalid. Re-enter number: "); 
            num = reader.nextDouble();                         
        } 

        return num;
    }
}
```

As you said, you have tried to enter `1.0`, `2.8` and etc. Please try with this code.

**Note : Please enter number one by one, on separate lines. I mean, enter `2.7`, press enter and then enter second number (e.g. `6.7`).**

Comment: Like I said, I only type in double value such as 1.0, 5.8, etc and that still displays the same message

Comment: @TrầnTrung copy whole code and compile  and run it. And, try to give some input, which you have tried earlier. Also, please check my **Note** at the last of my answer. And, let me know.If you got the solution, then also let me know.

Comment: I think I found the problem, because my computer only recognize the ',' as for the fractional part while the inputs I used are with '.', this is why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using a dot, like: 1.2, try to input like this: 1,2.

Comment: try changing the scanner locale: `.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)`

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the manual user input loop, after the scanner has read your first input it will pass the carriage/return into the next line which will also be read; of course, that is not what you wanted.

You can try this

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    reader.next(); 
}
```

or alternatively, you can consume that carriage return before reading your next double input by calling

> reader.next()

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. 
Strange, but the reason was that the object Scanner interprets fractions depending on localization of system. 
If the current localization uses a comma to separate parts of the fractions, the fraction with the dot will turn into type String. 
Hence the error ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing write input to the console ?

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
num = reader.nextDouble();
```

This is return double if you just enter number like 456. 
In case you enter a string or character instead,it will throw java.util.InputMismatchException when it tries to do  num = reader.nextDouble() .