# I want to ask on what's going on, whenever I try to run it, it keeps giving me run time error like this

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want user to enter the number of rows for the following pattern, so please mark my mistake.As I am beginner in java so please suggest me some book also.
  This pattern must be shown

```
**********   
*********    
********     
*******      
******       
*****        
****         
***          
**           
*
```

And this is a code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class pattern{
public static void main (String agrs[]){

int n;
Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the no. of rows in the pattern");
n= in.nextInt();
{
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{   for(int j=0; j<=i;j++)

System.out.print(" * ");
System.out.println(" ");
}}
}}

  ERROR   ...... 
 enter the no. of rows in the pattern
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at pattern.main(pattern.java:8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) on the oracle site, the expanation for the Exception is:

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

This Exception is thrown when non integer input is entered.

You need to add a try/catch to catch this, and inform the user of wrong input.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternTest {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {

        int n = -1;     

        do
        {
            try {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
                System.out.println("enter the no. of rows in the pattern");
                n = in.nextInt();               
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.print("Please enter only an integer.");
            }
        }while(n == -1);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            System.out.print(" * ");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

    }
}
```

**Update**

```
int n = -1;     

do
{
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("enter the no. of rows in the pattern");
        n = in.nextInt();               
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.print("Please enter only an integer.");
    }
}while(n == -1);

for (int rowNumber = n; rowNumber > 0; rowNumber--) {

    for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < rowNumber; columnNumber++)
    System.out.print("*");  

    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: but this is only showing that there is an error ,not giving an optimal output.

Comment: @ashish Your original question was focused on the error. In any case, update includes the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).It's clear here
Returns the next token as a long. If the next token is not a float or is out of range, InputMismatchException is thrown.

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/input-mismatch-exception).