# Java try and catch method

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am a beginner of java, and when I following the display 2.12 of Absolute Java. The console shows there is thread in 'main. I put the text file in the root directory of my program. And I also have double check for the code. I have no idea how to fix it. I am using eclipse to code in the macOS and java is the newest version. Thanks for your help
The code shows like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class TextFileDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner fileIn = null;
        try
        {
            fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("player.rtf"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("file not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int highscore;
        String name;

        System.out.println("Text left to read? " +    fileIn.hasNextLine());
        highscore = fileIn.nextInt();
        fileIn.nextLine();
        name = fileIn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("High score: " + highscore);
        System.out.println("Text left to read? " + fileIn.hasNextLine());
        fileIn.close();
    }
```

**And this is my console display:**

[image: And this is my console display]

Comment: Replace FileNotFoundException by InputMismatchException.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicated that, when reading from your data file, the first thing you tried to read with `nextInt()` was not actually an integer.

Examine what is in the file.  Specifically, in an editor which treats the file as unformatted data, like `notepad`.

Your file name suggests the file you are reading is an `.rtf` file, or "Rich Text Format".  Scanner cannot read that.

Save the file as a plain text file.

Comment: Thanks, I try to use .txt file before, but it is the same problem

Comment: Just renaming `player.rtf` to `player.txt` does not change the encoding of the file; make sure to **save** the file as plain text.  If you are certain the file is plain text, as a temporary debugging measure, replace `highscore = fileIn.nextInt(); fileIn.nextLine();` with `highscore = 1234; System.out.println("Line = "+fileIn.nextLine());` and report to us what the output was for further debugging assistance.

Comment: I checked the file information which shows it is plain text. I changed the code as your instruction and there is no error appear. But the result is weird , like this:                                                                                                      Text left to read? true
Line = {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf460
Name: {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
High score: 1234
Text left to read? true

Comment: Yup!  That's an `RTF` encoded document; it begins: "`{\rtf1`".  You'll need to open it with an RTF aware program, and save-as a regular plain text file.  Reading just the text of an rtf document is way beyond the capabilities of your `Scanner` class.

Comment: On MacOS, the `TextEdit` will work for this.  Open the document, then "Format -> Make Plain Text", and save to a new name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the result ! Your knowledge is amazing !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am right but this error is throw because you might be trying to match a int to a string. Probably, due to the content of the file you might want to upload that to the question too. If you just going to print to console I suggest you convert all of them to string.

This might help also
[Input Mismatch Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/input-mismatch-exception)