# Why am i getting this error?(Double Array Method)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am getting the error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909) at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530) at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160) at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119) at
>   SearchArray.main(SearchArray.java:10)"

when I have this code running. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SearchArray {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        //imput array size
        //imput array digits
        //imput element to search for

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        double array[] = new double[size];

        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++){
           array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }

        double digit = scan.nextDouble();
        boolean bool = findElement(array,digit);

        if(bool == true){
           System.out.println(digit + " was found in the array");
        }else if(bool == false){
           System.out.println(digit + " was NOT found in the array");
        }
    }

    public static boolean findElement(double[] array, double digit){
        boolean bool = false;
        //accepts double array, double  & returns boolean
        //check if numnber entered is in the array

        for(int i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++){
            if(array[i] == digit){
               bool = true;
            }else{
               bool = false;
            }
        }

        return bool;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I believe you're entering something that's not a number, when the `Scanner` is expecting an `int`.

Comment: Can you provide the input details. So that we can easily debug the code.You might be running into problem @David Wallace stating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input Mismatch Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/input-mismatch-exception)

Comment: Im using my college websites VPL and it is giving me the error when they do random numbers but not whenever I do one.

Answer (score 1):

> public class [InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)
>   Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14027583/7421645 and try understand why you are getting the exception, e.g. try to catch the exception:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage()); //try to find out specific reason.
}
```

I'd also try inputting the test data as a `String` first, at least until you are sure that your expected inputs provides the expected outputs.

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
```