# Rock Paper Scissor Game wont run

Tags: java

Ok, hi every one. This is my first time here on stackoverflow, I've doing a lot of searching here so I figure that this would be a good place to get some answers. I am a beginner programmer currently in school. I am working on my assignment of creating a rock, paper, scissors game. I feel like my code is good so far, I compiled it but it wont run at all. Take a look:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class RPSGame {


    public static void gameModeSelect ()
    {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors 1.0 !\n Please select your game mode: ");
    System.out.println("1. Player vs. Computer\n 2. Player vs. Player ");
    }

    public static void winLoss ()
    {
    int P1 = 0, P2 = 0;

    if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'R'){
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'P'){
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }    
    if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'S'){
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'R'){
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
    if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'P'){
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'S'){
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

    int P1;
        P1 = 0;
    int P2;
        P2 = 0;
    int modeSelect;
    modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();

    gameModeSelect ();
    if (modeSelect == 1){
        System.out.println("Oops, this feature in currently unavailable. Play with a friend for now :-)");
    } else if (modeSelect == 2){

        System.out.println("Rules of the game:  R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors\n Good luck! ");

        System.out.println("Player one: Enter your move");
        P1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Player two: Enter your move");
        P2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    } else if (modeSelect > 2){
        winLoss();

    }

  }
}
```

It compiles without errors but nothing runs, however when I enter anything in the running section I get this error:

```
run:
S
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at RPSGame.main(RPSGame.java:41)
C:\Users\AVLG2\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 seconds)
```

I'm stuck here, and my assignment is due tomorrow. Any suggestions? It would be highly appreciated. BTW, glad to be part of the stackoverflow community!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input Mismatch Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/input-mismatch-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void gameModeSelect() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors 1.0 !\n Please select your game mode: ");
    System.out.println("1. Player vs. Computer\n 2. Player vs. Player ");
}

public static void winLoss(char P1, char P2) {

    if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'R') {
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'P') {
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
    if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'S') {
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'R') {
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
    if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'P') {
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'S') {
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    char P1;
    char P2;
    int modeSelect;

    gameModeSelect();
    modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (modeSelect == 1) {
        System.out.println("Oops, this feature in currently unavailable. Play with a friend for now :-)");
    } else if (modeSelect == 2) {

        System.out.println("Rules of the game:  R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors\n Good luck! ");

        System.out.println("Player one: Enter your move");
        P1 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Player two: Enter your move");
        P2 = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        winLoss(P1, P2);

    }
}
```

1. You have to choose the game mode: modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();
2. Read the players inputs: P1 = keyboard.next().charAt(0); (& P2 row)
3. Evaluate the game: invoke the winLoss function with appropiate values

Comment: I'm not sure if this reply is permitted since I read "there's only questions and answers." But thank you! I originally attempted to make P1 & P2 char but could not get it to work. Your suggestion of "keyboard.next().charAt(0);" was the key that I couldn't find. Thanks again. I think I got it from here!

Answer (score 2):

You don't see anything because in `main` method you invoke

```
modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();
```

before printing anything. This call stops main thread until user will provide some data to read. If data will be of type `int` flow of control will move you to next line, if it will not be `int` exception will be thrown (like in your case since `R` is not valid `int`).

To let user know what is going on print message which explains that program is waiting for his input:

```
System.out.print("Please provide game mode (<mode explanation here>): ");
modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Also when you are asking user for characters you can't use `nextInt()` because `R` is not `int`. Use `next()` instead.

---

In case of problems also read:

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)
[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned `Scanner#nextInt()` can only parse Integers entered by users. For characters it throws an exception.

Here your code with minor changes to make it work:

```
public class RPSGame {

public static void gameModeSelect() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors 1.0 !\n Please select your game mode: ");
    System.out.println("1. Player vs. Computer\n 2. Player vs. Player ");
}

public static void winLoss() {
    int P1 = 0, P2 = 0;

    if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'R') {
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'P') {
        System.out.println("Paper covers rock!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
    if (P1 == 'R' && P2 == 'S') {
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'R') {
        System.out.println("Rock breaks scissors!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
    if (P1 == 'S' && P2 == 'P') {
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper!\nPlayer one wins!");
    } else if (P1 == 'P' && P2 == 'S') {
        System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper!\nPlayer two wins!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String P1 = null;
    String P2 = null;
    int modeSelect;

    gameModeSelect();
    modeSelect = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (modeSelect == 1) {
        System.out.println("Oops, this feature in currently unavailable. Play with a friend for now :-)");
    } else if (modeSelect == 2) {

        System.out.println("Rules of the game:  R = Rock, P = Paper, S = Scissors\n Good luck! ");

        System.out.println("Player one: Enter your move");
        P1 = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Player two: Enter your move");
        P2 = keyboard.next();

    } else if (modeSelect > 2) {
        winLoss();

    }

}
}
```

The evaluation is missing, but I guess that's up to you.