# Using scanners to get data from a txt file

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to get the Name, Surname and birthdate out of a txt file
this is what I have

```
Scanner scFile = new Scanner (new File("BirthDates.txt"));
        String Name;
        int BirthDates = 0;
        String Line = null;

            while(scFile.hasNext())
            {
                Line = scFile.nextLine();
                Scanner scLine = new Scanner(Line).useDelimiter("#");

                Name = scLine.next();
                BirthDates = scLine.nextInt();
                scLine.close();
                System.out.println(Name + BirthDates);
            }
        scFile.close();
```

[The errors that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnwN2.png)    [The txt File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbegH.png)

Comment: Please don't post images. Post the stacktrace here

Comment: And explain what research you did on whatever the error is and what you did to try and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem source :**

In this line : `BirthDates = scLine.nextInt();`, you try to get a birth day as `int` , but you read the second value after `#` like `Jackson`.

**Solution :**

Get the full name, then get your birth day :

```
  Name = scLine.next();
  secondeName = scLine.next();
  BirthDates = scLine.nextInt();
```

For more, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/why-am-i-getting-inputmismatchexception)