# error while taking String input in java

Tags: java

[image]

```
package test;
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
        String s;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        s=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

I don't know why this error is coming.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   test.Test.main(Test.java:12) C:\Users\MOHIT KUMAR
>   SINGH\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-
> snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: This code does not seem to bear much relation to the error in your stack trace.

Comment: still same error.

Comment: No offense meant, but you could have made some research on your own before asking the whole community for that kind of simple problem.

Comment: I already did but not finding any of it useful.

Comment: First, your stacktrace does not match your code: in your code, you use `nextLine` though there is only `nextInt` in the stacktrace. It's not the same class name too... Then, you take a look at the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt() : InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range.
This explains the exception.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting InputMismatchException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/why-am-i-getting-inputmismatchexception)

Comment: `nextLine` doesn't even throw the exception you mention...

Comment: @sjahan I copied and pasted the same error i am getting.

Comment: @MohitKumarsingh I think you do not get it. As I already told you: the code and the stacktrace does not match. The error is caused by a call to `nextInt` which does not exist in your code, which means you don't actually show your code... Or you don't know what you actually run. **Once again, `nextLine` does not throw InputMismatchException**

Comment: Ok, I can confirm what I just said: you don't know what you actually run. Here, this is the `Test` class you run, not the `NewClass`.

Comment: @sjahan ,Now i get it . thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.InputMismatchException`-In order to deal with this exception you must verify that the input data of your application meet its specification. When this error is thrown, the format of the input data is incorrect and thus, you must fix it, in order for your application to proceed its execution.

Comment: but I am giving string as an input.

Comment: @MohitKumarsingh if you are giving string as input then You should not get this error. Even if you give any symbol or integer as input then It should print without any error due to string input.

Comment: but I am getting this error .

Comment: @MohitKumarsingh Please put your complete code here alongwith complete error.

Comment: package test;
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   String s;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        s=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
}

Comment: @MohitKumarsingh not here in comment. Edit your question and add updated question

Comment: this is complete code.

Comment: @MohitKumarsingh how you are running this code.

Comment: I using netBeans and running by pressing that green triangle button

Comment: @MohitKumarsingh I have copied and tested your code exactly. It is working fine in eclipse. Please check you must be having some other issue.

Comment: @NitinBisht Ok thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your main class but there no argument/parameter in your `main` method. You should do like this

```
public static void main(String[] arr) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: I did corrected this thing but still nothing.

Comment: You debug your code..?