# i get an exception in "main" thread in VS code

Tags: java

I get an exception in my code, so it doesnt show more than the first print request, te problem seems to start at line 12
i dont know if i need something else, or is a problem with the int variable type

````
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at App.main(App.java:12)```
````

```
// En un supermercado se trabajan 5 días a la semana. EupJava. Que lea la cantidad de empleados que trabajan por día y las horas que trabajo cada empleado por día. Imprimir:
//- Cuantos empleados trabajaron el día 1
//- Numero de empleado que trabajo más horas, cuantas horas fueron y en que día fue
//- Total de horas trabajadas el día 5
import java.util.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
        int i, empleados, h, e1=0, mhora=0, hrs, nempleado=0, dia = 0, dia5 = 0;
        for(i = 1; 1 <= 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Pon el numero de empleados por dia" + i);
    empleados = leer.nextInt();
    if(i == 1) {
        e1 = empleados;
    }

    for(h = 1; h < empleados; h++) {
        System.out.println("Pon el numero de horas");
        hrs = leer.nextInt();
        if (hrs > mhora) {
            mhora = hrs;
            dia = i;
            dia = i;
        }
        if (i == 5){
            dia5 = dia5 + hrs;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La cantidad de empleados que trabajo el día 1 es de"+e1);
    System.out.println("El empleado que trabajo más horas fue el"+nempleado+"trabajo"+mhora+"y fue en el día"+dia);
    System.out.println("El total de horas rabajadas en el día 5 fue de"+ dia5);
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: From the _javadoc_ of class `java.util.InputMismatchException`: _Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type._ You are not entering a valid integer when this line of your code executes: `empleados = leer.nextInt();` Are you entering a very big number that is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it seems like you might be inputting characters instead of numbers.

Specifically at this stacktrace:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
     means that it doesn't match a specified pattern
         possibly int>String doesn't work?
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
-----------------------------------------------------------
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        ----------------------------------------------------------
                           Exception in nextInt
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        at App.main(App.java:12)
```

sources
InputMismatchException -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

If you mean by the locale, if you're inputting 1.2 or such, try changing the locale by using `.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)`, as it could be interpreting something that's not like `1,2` as a string.

sources
locale -- [Why am I getting InputMismatchException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027537/why-am-i-getting-inputmismatchexception)